# ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "2020-06-0700:00:00"

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to run the Select query(linked server) from SSMS to get the data from PostgreSQL on AWS cloud. My query is running fine in SSMS but as soon as I enter the following line of code

```
and c.created_date >=concat(to_char(CURRENT_DATE - interval '7 day', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),' 00:00:00'):: timestamp

and c.created_date <= concat(to_char(CURRENT_DATE - interval '1 day','yyyy-mm-dd') ,' 23:59:59') ::timestamp
```

it starts giving me ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "2020-06-0700:00:00";

created_date field in my PostgreSQL is timestamp without timezone

Which datatype should I chose which is compatible with SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things. `concat()` and `to_char()` are not needed and the root cause of the problem.

The start of the day 7 days back can be obtained using: `current_date - 7`. As that doesn't have a time part, a comparison with a `timestamp` column will automatically assume `00:00:00`.

If you want to compare everything up to yesterday midnight, simply use `< current_date`.

So your expression can be simplified to:

```
and created_date >= current_date - 7
and created_date < current_date
```

Note the **`<`** instead of `<=` in the second condition.

If you want to be explicit about the time, you could use

```
and created_date >= (current_date - 7) + time '00:00:00'
and created_date < current_date + time '00:00:00'
```

But that's not needed and is absolutely identical to the first condition.

---

`created_date < current_date` is roughly equivalent to `created_date <= (current_date - 1) + time '23:59:59'` (which is your initial intention).

However, it's only *roughly* equivalent because your attempt isn't actually correct as it misses the time between `23:59:59.000000` and `23:59:59.999999`, that's why it's better to use `<` with the *next day's* start.

Comment: Excellent Explanation